# React - How can I strip top level div from a React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When writing JSX, I sometimes need to create a top level element so the code will compile.  For example, this won't compile.

```
const routesList1 = (
    <Route exact path="/link1" component={Link1UI}/>
    <Route exact path="/link2" component={Link2UI}/>
)
```

But this will:

```
const routesList1 = (
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/link1" component={Link1UI}/>
    <Route exact path="/link2" component={Link2UI}/>
  </div>
)
```

Usually wrapping other React elements in a <div> works fine, but not always.  So I'd like to know if I was forced to create a top level element to get the code to compile, can I later strip it off?  If so how?

Below is a conceptual example of a problem I ran into with React router's Switch element.

```
import react from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const routesList1 = (
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/link1" component={Link1UI}/>
    <Route exact path="/link2" component={Link2UI}/>
  </div>
)

const routesList2 = (
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/link3" component={Link3UI}/>
    <Route exact path="/link4" component={Link4UI}/>
  </div>
)

function stripDivFrom(reactElement) {
    reactElement.Children.toArray();
}

class MyApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                {stripDivFrom(routesList1)}
                {stripDivFrom(routesList2)}
                <Route exact path="/help" component={HelpUI}/>
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}
```

I provide this simplified example code so readers can understand what I'm asking.

**I'm looking to get an answer to the question, not for a work around.**

The question is: How can I get the children of a given react/JSX element?  How can I change the stripDivFrom() function so that it works.

NOTE: The stripDivFrom() function currently doesn't work.  The Children property doesn't is undefined (when I observe it in Chrome debugger).  I found it when looking at the React source code but I'm obviously misunderstanding something.  The browser console has an error that says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of undefined.

#### Updated

EDITED: After this question was asked, in React introduced a better solution to this problem.

In React 16.2.0 the component `<React.Fragment>` was added which solves this problem.

The following is how the code would now loook:

```
    const routesList1 = (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Route exact path="/link1" component={Link1UI}/>
        <Route exact path="/link2" component={Link2UI}/>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
```

Comment: why do you need to strip a div when you can return multiple elements as an array

Comment: Using an array is IMO a work around and avoids the problem so my question goes away.  I'm trying to understand if it is possible to do what I'm trying to do.  But to answer your question, the reason I don't like using an array is it makes refactoring turn into a transform not just a copy/paste.  So the JSX turns into rtn.push(<Route/>), rtn.push(<Route/>) return array.  Now the JSX has turned into Javascript calls.  Sorry if this isn't clear but answering in a comment leaves my answer constrained for space reasons.

Comment: Understood, As you already said you dont want workarounds in your question so I just confirmed why you wanna do it, in comments

Comment: One of the reasons to strip the top level div is to avoid extra divs which when introduced break CSS.  React has has since introduced `<React.Fragment>` which is the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be available by `element.props.children`.

Write it like this:

```
function stripDivFrom(reactElement) {
    return reactElement.props.children;
}
```

> [What is props.children in react?](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx)

In JSX expressions that contain both an opening tag and a closing tag, the content between those tags is passed as a special **prop: props.children**.

React elements are basically objects, check this example:

```
const element = (
  <h1 className="greeting">
    Hello, world!
  </h1>
);
```

Object created by react will be:

```
const element = {
  type: 'h1',
  props: {
    className: 'greeting',
    children: 'Hello, world'
  }
};
```

Check this: **[JSX Represents Objects](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects)**

Working Code (style on wrapper div will not reflect in ui):

```js
const hello = <div style={{color:'red'}}><div>Hello</div><div>World</div></div>

class Game extends React.Component {

  a(el){
    return el.props.children;
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="game-layout">
        {this.a(hello)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id ='container'/>
```

working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/0cwueg7j/

Comment: **I tested your example, and it works**.  In my code, it doesn't.  I get reactElement.props is undefined, I'm trying to track down why.

Comment: OK, I tracked it down.  I had a bug/misunderstanding of how react works.  I was returning a function which when called would render instead of returning the React.Component, when I changed my code to return the React.Component things worked!  My experimentation is at https://jsfiddle.net/PatS2265/8ub3epcd/.
Also, **thank you for creating the JSFiddle version of my question and providing an answer.**

Comment: An important thing I learned from this, is that SomeObject.props has information that is available outside of the SomeObject.render() method.  **I incorrectly thought that the this.props was only set by the React framework as a mechanism to pass things from the parent to the child.** Obviously a react rookie (in training :-)).